# Ordering of Collect in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have some expression which I want to gather various linear terms (CxxP, CxyP, CyyP) from. Currently I am using:

```
aaa = Collect[ expr, {CxxP, CxyP, CyyP}]
```

but the result is not returned in the order I specify (i.e. I would like CxxP to appear first etc):

```
-(1 + a) CxyP (a GC) - CxxP (k^2 l^2 + GC)
```

The reason for wanting this ordering is so I can extract the specific terms I need. If there is an easier way to do this I would love to know, e.g.

```
In[] = ExtractTerm[aaa, CxxP]
Out[] = -(k^2 l^2 + GC)
```

Using CoefficientList doesn't preserve the order either, and doesn't pick up coefficients for terms that aren't there i.e. I want to be explicitly told that there aren't any CyyP terms.

Thanks, Ewan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understood you right, you can make an ordered list of coefficients like this:

```
Coefficient[aaa,#]&/@{CxxP, CxyP, CyyP}
```

Comment: Perfect! Could you clarify how this works perhaps? I'm not familiar with the &/@ notation...

Comment: @Hemmer /@ is just an infix form of `Map[]` and & indicates anonymous function with # as a parameter. You can just select stuff that you don't know and press F1 and read all about it.